# Check data quality by join of a query result to a sub query with by using test data in the query with union all

Tags: sql

I'm working on checking data quality. We want to check a list of names a user gives us by forming it in a subquery because we don't have permission to create tables or temp tables since it's a third party database. I can quickly concatenate the list together in spreadsheet formulas. How do I right join to the result of a query to find out if any are missing. This is also a great example of how to include test data in your script without creating test tables or temp tables!
Version SQL Server 2008 R

```
--table to check for data quality

SELECT LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, PEOPLE_CODE_ID FROM 
test.DBO.PEOPLE WHERE
last_name = 'Berd' and first_name = 'Alivia' OR
last_name = 'Arny' and first_name = 'Jase' OR
last_name = 'Barny' and first_name = 'Cale'
AS A

right join --list from user
        (
select 'Abbie' as first_name, 'Bail' as last_name
UNION select 'Jenny' as first_name, 'Bleee' as last_name
UNION select 'Jase' as first_name, 'Arny' as last_name
UNION select 'Jason' as first_name, 'Bussey' as last_name
) AS B
WHERE A.LAST_NAME = B.LAST_NAME
AND A.FIRST_NAME = B.FIRST_NAME
```

Comment: A [Table Value Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples) might be helpful for the right side of the join. Any rows from the right side that aren't matched by rows on the left can be identified by the NULL values in all of the columns from the left table. That might be clearer with table aliases on the columns you are selecting, e.g. `select B.Last_Name, B.First_Name, ...`. Of course, using `on` instead of `where` will keep the join `outer` rather than making it `inner`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the lines that DO NOT match:

```
SELECT A.LAST_NAME, A.FIRST_NAME, PEOPLE_CODE_ID
FROM  test.DBO.PEOPLE AS A  

right join --list from user
        (
select 'Abbie' as first_name, 'Bail' as last_name
UNION select 'Jenny' as first_name, 'Bleee' as last_name
UNION select 'Jase' as first_name, 'Arny' as last_name
UNION select 'Jason' as first_name, 'Bussey' as last_name
) AS B ON  A.LAST_NAME = B.LAST_NAME AND A.FIRST_NAME = B.FIRST_NAME


WHERE (A.last_name = 'Berd' and A.first_name = 'Alivia')
    OR (A.last_name = 'Arny' and A.first_name = 'Jase')
    OR (A.last_name = 'Barny' and A.first_name = 'Cale')
AND B.LAST_NAME IS NULL
```

Change to IS NOT NULL for the matching lines or use something like

```
CASE WHEN B.last_name IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS HasMatch
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure I'm understanding your question but it sounds like you want to compare your `people` table against a list of users and return which users aren't in that list?

If so, here's one option using `not exists`:

```
with userstosearch as (
    select 'Abbie' as first_name, 'Bail' as last_name
    union all select 'Jenny', 'Bleee' 
    union all select 'Jase', 'Arny' 
    union all select 'Jason', 'Bussey'
) 
select u.* 
from userstosearch u
where not exists (
    select 1
    from test.DBO.PEOPLE p
    where u.firstname = p.firstname and u.lastname = p.lastname
)
```

---

If you prefer to use an `outer join`:

```
...
select u.* 
from userstosearch u
    left join test.DBO.PEOPLE p on u.firstname = p.firstname and u.lastname = p.lastname
where p.firstname is null
```